# Selecting a specific table with XPath

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, screen-scraping

I've got an XHTML document, and I want to select the only table in it with class="index".

If I understand correctly, the descendant axis will select all nodes directly and indirectly descending from the current node, so here's what I've got.

```
//descendant::table[@class="index"]
```

It doesn't appear to be working when tested with xmlstarlet. Is my tool broke, or is the XPath expression wrong?

Comment: If you post sample input, we could know for sure whether the tool is broken. (For example, maybe you need to use a namespace prefix.) One quick note, //descendant:: is redundant. In this case, use either /descendant::table (just one slash) or simply //table. "//" is shorthand for "/descendant-or-self::node()/"

Comment: metacritic.com/film/highscores.shtml is one such example, but it has to be passed through Tidy and some other tweaks before it's XSLT ready.

Comment: Do the tweaks include the addition of the XHTML namespace declaration? In XPath, you have to declare the namespace (and use a prefix in your expression) if you want to select nodes by name that use a namespace.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your example page (metacritic.com/film/highscores.shtml), I would say you need to use:

```
//TABLE[@CLASS="index"] 
(or /descendant::TABLE[@CLASS="index"])
```

This is because the TABLE with CLASS index is written in upper case on your example page (XML and XPath are case sensitive).

This will work if you are targeting a specific page, but will probably become a problem if different pages use different case for the same html tags.

Then you'll need an abomination like

```
//TABLE[@CLASS="index" or @class="index" or @Class="index" or ...]
|//table[@CLASS="index" or @class="index" or ...]
|...
```

So you'll probably need to keep using Tidy before extracting information, or switch to a tool that's specialized for HTML scraping (instead of XPath)

Comment: indeed, tidy is part of the process, but it tanks on some poorly formatted HTML that puts a td inside a form. I've already got a nearly working version based on BeautifulSoup and uTidy; figuring out how to fix ugly form via tidy or sed is the next step I think.

Answer (score 4):

I think `//table[@class="index"]` is what you want

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the `descendant` axis selects all nodes descending from the context node. But the key here is the context node.

For instance, `descendant::span` will retrieve all `span` descendants of the current node. In the same vein, `descendant::*` will retrieve all descendant elements of the current node.

If you need to match the table as well as children, the XPath you provided works fine during my test :

```
//descendant::table[@class="index"]
```

... selects the Table itself and childnodes.

If you only need to match the table's children, first match the node you want *and then* match its descendants:

```
//table[@class="index"]/descendant::*
```

.. Selects only child nodes of the Table.

Answer (score 0):

use this code

```
   let $info :=($p//descendant::TABLE[@class="index"])
        return $info
```